# Add prompt to mark as answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was just on movies.stackexchange.com and I discovered they have an automated prompt that comes up if you, as the person who wrote the question, upvote an answer:

[image]

I think this is a must-have for Blender's site, because when someone comes to the site, questions with clearly identified answers are more valuable to answer-seekers.

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think this is on every SE site, however only shown to low-rep users.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feature reminder is already active across the network. It is a bit of just-in-time learning geared towards newer users. Once you have (I believe) 1000 rep, the prompt is no longer displayed.